# Issues with installing Azure specific PowerShell modules for writing to Azure Tables

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell

We are currently rolling out Windows 10 (1903) devices via Intune, and we have requirements to install Azure PowerShell modules under the System account for the devices to communicate and write data to Azure tables. There is a script running under the system account that will write data to Azure every so often.

None of these modules are loading, even when we manually copy them across to the correct location and try the 'offline' method, and we have noticed the following errors on the clients within Event Viewer:

**Cannot convert value "2.0.0-preview" to type "System.Version". Error: "Input string was not in a correct format."**

The modules that I am trying to install are:

**Install-Module -Name Az -AllowClobber -Force | Out-Null**

**Install-Module -Name AzureRmStorageTable -RequiredVersion 2.0.1 -Force | Out-Null**

Any advice/help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try the latest table module `AzTable `.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/tables/table-storage-how-to-use-powershell#managing-table-entities

Comment: Thanks George. I have just noticed that some Az modules have installed, including the AzTable module - but the above error still appears - and no data is being written. The following is also now showing within Event Viewer - "The script 'AzureRMStorageTableCoreHelper.psm1' cannot be run because the following modules that are specific by the "#requires" statements of the script are missing: Az.Storage"... Az.Storage will not seem to import

Comment: You shouldn't use both the Az and AzureRm modules.  I would encourage you to switch over to all of the Az modules.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to Github issue: [Can't install PowerShell Az - Cannot convert value "2.0.0-preview" Windows 10](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/9430)

If your `PowerShellGet` module version is less than `1.6.0`, you might encounter this issue. You may update the `PowerShellGet` module nad have another try.